# What are the best defensive strategies in NBA 2K11?

Tags: nba2k11

I would like to know what are the best defensive strategies to take on nba 2k11. Playing zones, man on man, double team traps, etc; or is it best to switch defenses through the game.

Answer (score 1):

What mode is this for?  I've mostly played only single player mode in the 3/4 slot so its the only one I can relate to, and I've mostly had luck with man to man defence while occasionally calling for a double team when they pass the ball inside to their big man.

Occasionally, I rotate in for a block attempt when its obvious the ball handler has their man beat, but more often than not you'll get burned when you leave your guy open if they are a sharpshooter.

Comment: I have that happen, I am finding that your starting man to man defense is fine when you are playing an average player.  But when you go up against a really good player they usually pick apart your defense and thats when you need to look at other sets of d that you have available.

Comment: Playing online.